# How to render different html elements in the play view template by a boolean value?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

If I pass a boolean value to the view, for example "checked", how to show the different html elements according to the checked value(that is , true or false) ?

```
#{if ${checked}}
     <p>aaa</p>
#{/if}
#{else}
     <p>bbb</p>
#{/else}
```

I try the above code but failed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#{if checked}
     <p>aaa</p>
#{/if}
#{else}
     <p>bbb</p>
#{/else}
```

The ${} syntax, is only for printing values into your template. Inside the #{if } tag, playframework expects groovy syntax.

Also, check out the [documentation for the #{if} tag](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/tags#if).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @aaberg response with an inline if :

```
<input type="checkbox" ${checked ? 'checked="checked"' : ''} />
<span>The previous checkbox is ${checked ? "checked" : "not checked"} !</span>
```